# Akka supervision strategies and termination

Tags: akka, akka-supervision, akka-actor

I am brand new to Akka and am trying to wrap my head around `SupervisorStrategies` and child actor termination. I have several very similar concerns.

First off, my *understanding* is that if an actor creates another actor (via `context.actorOf(...)`), then it is automatically the created actor's parent/supervisor. This is the *only* way an actor can be a parent of/supervisor of another actor.

If anything I have said above is incorrect, please begin by correcting me! But, assuming I'm more or less on track, then what happens when multiple parent actors create instances of the same child actor:

```
// Groovy pseudo-code.
class Fizz extends UntypedActor {
    @Override
    void onReceive(Object message) {
        ActorRef buzz = context.system.actorOf(Props.create(Buzz), "buzz")
        buzz.tell("Hello buzz!", self)
    }
}

class Foo extends UntypedActor {
    @Override
    void onReceive(Object message) {
        ActorRef buzz = context.system.actorOf(Props.create(Buzz), "buzz")
        buzz.tell("Meh!", self)
    }
}
```

In the above example, are `Fizz` and `Foo` parents to the same `Buzz` actor instance, or two instances of `Buzz` altogether? If it's multiple instances, can I assume that terminating one instance only terminates that instance? Or if `Foo` terminates/stops its `Buzz` instance, does that also terminate/stop `Fizz`'s instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all these two are different:

```
context.system.actorOf(Props.create(Buzz), "buzz")
context.actorOf(Props.create(Buzz), "buzz")
```

`context.system.actorOf()` creates the top level user actor. In order to create child actor, you have to use `context.actorOf()`. The rest of the answer will assume that you use the latter method.

Akka's actor supervision system is hierarichical.
That means that each actor has only one parent.
So your quesion:

> are Fizz and Foo parents to the same Buzz actor instance,

is false, `Buzz` actor created from `Foo`, and `Buzz` created from `Fizz`, are different instance, which has different parent.

You can confirm it by viewing the path of the actor.
`Buzz` created by `Foo` has path something like `akka://<system_name>/user/foo/buzz`, and `Buzz` created by `Fizz` has path something like `akka://<system_name>/user/fizz/buzz`

(I don't use java, but maybe you can get the actor path by something like `getPath()` method of `ActorRef` or `Actor`)

Additionally the `Buzz` actor created by `context.system.actorOf()` has path something like `akka://<system_name>/user/buzz`, which is directly supervied by the [User Guardinan](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.12/general/supervision.html#user-guardian) actor.

So the relation between the actor path is:

- `akka://<system_name>/user/fizz/buzz` (instace of `Buzz`) is supervised  by `akka://<system_name>/user/fizz` (Instance of `Fizz`)
- `akka://<system_name>/user/foo/buzz` (another instance of `Buzz`) is supervised by `akka://<system_name>/user/foo` (instance of `Foo`) .

Therefore your main question:

> can I assume that terminating one instance only terminates that instance? Or if Foo terminates/stops its Buzz instance, does that also terminate/stop Fizz's instance?

the former is correct.

Read akka docs for more detail:

- http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.12/general/addressing.html
- http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.12/general/supervision.html

Comment: Thanks for help here @ymonad (+1) - can you just please confirm my statement that creating a child actor makes you its parent? I'm just worried that there might be some API call that a parent needs to make in order to "bind" a child actor to it, etc. Thanks again!

Comment: @smeeb No, there's no extra API needed to bind the actor as it's child. Just calling `context.actorOf()` inside the actor creates new child actor.